# How can I access the projected DOM before view init?

Tags: angular

Given the following component:

```
@Component({
  selector: "form-control",
  template: `
    <div class="form-group" #div>
      <label [for]="inputId">{{label}}</label>
      <ng-content></ng-content>
      <small [id]="helpId" class="form-text text-muted">{{help}}</small>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class FormControlComponent {
```

How can I access the DOM Element my caller provides to `<ng-content>` to get its id (or set one, if the id is undefined)?

**What I have tried**

I tried using `@ViewChild("div")`, and inspecting the DOM in ngAfterViewInit(), and was able to access the input, but propagating it's id to the outer component with `this.inputId = input.id` caused an `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError`, because angular had already evaluated `inputId`.

I then tried using `@ContentChild`, but don't want to require the caller to provide a template variable, and while `@ContentChild(NgControl)` matches a directive, I have no clue how to get the DOM element for that directive.

Comment: how do you use `form-control` component? show html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this is really easy if the element is known to be decorated by a directive:

```
export class FormControlComponent implements AfterContentInit {

  @ContentChild(NgControl, {read: ElementRef}) inputRef: ElementRef;

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    const input = <HTMLInputElement> this.inputRef.nativeElement;
    // do what you want here
  }
}
```

The angular docs really could mention the permitted values for `read` :-)